# Polymer 2.0: How is the path to bower_components resolved?

Tags: polymer-2.x

Here is my file structure:
[image]

The index.html file shown is the one under *my-listfilter\demo*.

How is 
`<link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">`
resolving to the bower_components directory?

Wouldn't ../../ have us starting one level above the my-listfilter directory? Thank you.

Comment: What http server did you have?

Comment: This is running via the CLI polymer serve command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the magic of `polyserve`.

> The local package is served at the URL /components/{bower-name}/, with
>   files served from the current directory. Other packages are served at
>   /components/{packageName} with files served from their directory under
>   ./bower_components/.

https://github.com/Polymer/polyserve

In other words, the mapping from current directory to URL (in priority order)

1. bower_components/ maps to /components/
2. * (everything else) maps to /components/my-listfilter/*, e.g. demo/index.html maps to /components/my-listfilter/demo/index.html (the literal, my-listfilter, comes from your bower.json)

### Why bother a demo sub-directory?

It is commonly seen as a place to put demo files when publishing your component to webcomponents.org. e.g.

The following [lines](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/blob/master/app-route.html#L81-L83) will generate **Demo** links under `<app-route>` on [its component page](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/elements/app-route).

```
@demo demo/index.html
@demo demo/data-loading-demo.html
@demo demo/simple-demo.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I find that explanation a bit confusing.  Would you be willing to map what you're describing to my file structure?

Comment: Ok, so the addition of a 'components' directory occurs at runtime, yes?  I see nothing in my source code that calls out a components directory.  So, with just accepting that as fact and seeing the paths you called out, I can see how ../../ would place us in the bower_components directory given the following `http://127.0.0.1:8001/components/my-listfilter/demo/` the first `../` would place us in my-listfilter dir and the second '../' would place us in the components directory. I'm not crazy about the fact that directories added at runtime.

Comment: I think you provided a good answer.  I want to see community replies from my last comment prior to accepting it.

Comment: In this example: https://imagebin.ca/v/3TwDqAssDHCW things are much more straightforward.  Wouldn't this be the ideal way to do things?  The paths in index.html match the directory structure excatly.

Comment: bower_components/ doesn't work when your component published on webcomponents.org

Comment: OK, I still don't understand why the polymer init does all this magical URL stuff. Again, how come the paths to the resources aren't simply as per the actual file structure?  At this point I'm not at all concerned about publishing to webcomponents.org. I wanted to take a simple app and put it on the web server.  Why all this convolution?

Comment: You can just ignore it, and treat files as static content on your web server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149685/discussion-between-frank-r-and-jeremiah2911).

Comment: Git repo moved to https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/polyserve